# How to read and identify color coded data(font and background) from excel file and data with complex table structure in python?

Tags: python, excel

I have an excel file that is conditionally formatted. It has different values for different font colours as well as cell background colours. How to identify this information? Additionally, the table structure is complex. Means single row header may contain merged cells/multiple values.
Example:
[image]

Please help. Thank you

Comment: Hey... this is a quite broad question but I'd recommend reading this chapter (I only had made a small look some time ago): https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/

Comment: ya...thanks..checking the link..

Answer (score 4):

using openpyxl you can read basic color in rgb hex type, but you need to check on python and openpyxl and this library is under development stage

`from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename='testfile.xlsx', read_only=True)
worksheet = wb.active
print(worksheet['A1'].font.color)`

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following and xlrd package, it will help you to solve your question.

```
 excelbook = xlrd.open_workbook("excel urt", formatting_info=True)
excel_sheets = excelbook.sheet_names()
for item, exsh in enumerate(excel_sheets):
excel_sheet = excelbook.sheet_by_index(item)
rows, cols = excel_sheet.nrows, excel_sheet.ncols
for row in range(rows):
for col in range(cols):
thecell = excel_sheet.cell(row, col)      
xfx = excel_sheet.cell_xf_index(row, col)
xf = excelbook.xf_list[xfx]
bgx = xf.background.pattern_colour_index
print bgx
```

Comment: Please edit the question properly for proper visibility. I need font colour identification as well, this will give me only background colour value.